# Watchdog in Python: Error: [Windows error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: python, watchdog, permissionerror

i created a watchdog in Python. It watches a folder (test_folder). If a certain file is created, I call a function that opens the file and creates a jpeg, which is the getting saved in the test_folder again.

The first iteration works just fine but when I upload a different file (different content and even slightly different name) there is the error:

```
Event: C:/Users/WEL4HO/Desktop/test_folder\AD1__Sampling2000KHz_AEKi-0.parquet created!
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\WEL4HO\.conda\envs\anaconda\lib\threading.py", line 980, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\WEL4HO\.conda\envs\anaconda\lib\site-packages\watchdog\observers\api.py", line 205, in run
    self.dispatch_events(self.event_queue)
  File "C:\Users\WEL4HO\.conda\envs\anaconda\lib\site-packages\watchdog\observers\api.py", line 381, in dispatch_events
    handler.dispatch(event)
  File "C:\Users\WEL4HO\.conda\envs\anaconda\lib\site-packages\watchdog\events.py", line 271, in dispatch
    self.on_any_event(event)
  File "C:\Users\WEL4HO\Desktop\test_folder\watchdog3.py", line 34, in on_any_event
    Final.GAF(event.src_path, 'test_watchdog.jpeg')
  File "C:\Users\WEL4HO\Desktop\test_folder\Final.py", line 18, in GAF
    df = pq.read_table(source=parquet_file).to_pandas()
  File "C:\Users\WEL4HO\.conda\envs\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyarrow\parquet\__init__.py", line 2737, in read_table
    dataset = _ParquetDatasetV2(
  File "C:\Users\WEL4HO\.conda\envs\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyarrow\parquet\__init__.py", line 2340, in __init__
    [fragment], schema=schema or fragment.physical_schema,
  File "pyarrow\_dataset.pyx", line 870, in pyarrow._dataset.Fragment.physical_schema.__get__
  File "pyarrow\error.pxi", line 144, in pyarrow.lib.pyarrow_internal_check_status
  File "pyarrow\error.pxi", line 111, in pyarrow.lib.check_status
PermissionError: [WinError 32] Failed to open local file 'C:/Users/WEL4HO/Desktop/test_folder/AD1__Sampling2000KHz_AEKi-0.parquet'. Detail: [Windows error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

This is my watchdog:

```
import sys
import time
import logging
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
import Final
import os
  
class OnMyWatch:
    watchDirectory = r'C:/Users/WEL4HO/Desktop/test_folder'
    def __init__(self):
        self.observer = Observer()
    def run(self):
        event_handler = Handler()
        self.observer.schedule(event_handler, self.watchDirectory, recursive = True)
        self.observer.start()
        try:
            while True:
                time.sleep(1)
        except:
            self.observer.stop() 
        self.observer.join()
        
class Handler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    @staticmethod
    def on_any_event(event):
        if event.is_directory:
            return None
  
        elif event.event_type == 'created':
            print(f'Event: {event.src_path} created!')
            #folder event.src_path -> folder raw -> file
            if event.src_path.endswith('Sampling2000KHz_AEKi-0.parquet'):
                Final.GAF(event.src_path, 'GAF_photo.jpeg')
            
if __name__ == '__main__':
    watch = OnMyWatch()
    watch.run()
```

This is my file with the function I call:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import ImageGrid
from pyts.image import GramianAngularField
import numpy as np
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
from pathlib import Path
from scipy.signal import savgol_filter
import pandas as pd
import datetime

def GAF (path, outputname):

    Sampling_rate = 2000000  #' Ae sample rate'
    parquet_file = path

    #convert data into numpy array
    df = pq.read_table(source=parquet_file).to_pandas()
    acoustic_emission_1 = df.values # convert the data into numpy array
    time =  len(acoustic_emission_1)/(Sampling_rate) #process length

    #downsampling
    downsampling_rate = 90
    acoustic_emission_1_clip= acoustic_emission_1[:len(acoustic_emission_1)-(len(acoustic_emission_1)%downsampling_rate)]
    acoustic_emission_1_downsampled = acoustic_emission_1_clip.reshape(-1, downsampling_rate).mean(axis=1)
    samplingrate_downsampled =  (Sampling_rate)/(downsampling_rate)

    #positive data in arr 
    arr = np.array([], dtype=np.uint16)
    counter=0
    negative_values=0
    for x in np.nditer(acoustic_emission_1_downsampled):
        if x < 0: 
            negative_values=negative_values+1
            pass
        else:
            arr = np.append(arr, acoustic_emission_1_downsampled[counter]) 
        counter=counter+1
        
    #new samplingrate
    u=(negative_values)/time
    samplingrate_new=samplingrate_downsampled-u

    #filter 
    window_length=int(round((len(arr)*0.285),0))
    if (window_length % 2) == 0:
       window_length=window_length+1
    else:
       pass
    print ('window_length:',window_length)

    y_filtered = savgol_filter(arr,window_length, 3)
    print ('nach filter', len(y_filtered))
    print ('Y filtered:', y_filtered)

    #x-axis 
    length=len(y_filtered) #länge AE werte
    x = np.array([], dtype=int) #array x achse (zeit) leer
    counter=0
    i=0 
    while i==0:
        x = np.append(x, counter)
        if counter == length-1:
            break
        counter=counter+1
    print ('x achse:', len(x))

    X=np.array([y_filtered, x], dtype=object)
    print (X)
    print (length)


    # Transform the time series into Gramian Angular Fields
    gasf = GramianAngularField(image_size=1000, method='summation')
    X_gasf = gasf.transform(X)


    # Show the images for the first time series
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))
    grid = ImageGrid(fig, 111,
                     nrows_ncols=(1, 1),
                     axes_pad=0.15,
                     share_all=True,
                     cbar_location="right",
                     cbar_mode="single",
                     cbar_size="7%",
                     cbar_pad=0.3,
                     )
    images = [X_gasf[0]]
    titles = ['Summation']
    for image, title, ax in zip(images, titles, grid):
        im = ax.imshow(image, cmap='rainbow', origin='lower')
        ax.set_title(title, fontdict={'fontsize': 12})
    ax.cax.colorbar(im)
    ax.cax.toggle_label(True)
    plt.suptitle('Gramian Angular Field', y=0.98, fontsize=16)
    
    fig.savefig(outputname, dpi=300)
    plt.close(fig)
    del fig 
    del df
```

Answer (score 0):

nvm, I fixed it. I added:

```
init_size = -1
    while True:
        current_size = os.path.getsize(event.src_path)
        if current_size == init_size:
            break
        else:
            init_size = os.path.getsize(event.src_path)
            time.sleep(2)
    print("file copy has now finished")
```